# Recovering the application id of an old application (Eclipse era)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a very old Android application, made with Eclipse with minsdk 7 and a very primitive gradle build script.
I have deeply refactored it using Android Studio and I have make it compatible with Android 5.0 (sdk 21).
Unfortunately when I install it on the phone Android sees it as a new application and not an update.
I suppose that it is due to different/missing application id in old application.
Can you help me in finding old application id? Or is there another way to force this app as an update and not a new app?
Thanks in advance for help,
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard tool in android sdk called "apkanalyzer". We have recovered the old apk and using apkanalyzer we extracted application id.

Answer (score 1):

It's not only the application ID that matters, but also the app must be signed with the same certificate that the old app was signed with.

Comment: Thanks for info but we were lucky and we recovered original certificate. It seems only application id is missing.